# Lower the size of a Webflow persistance-context using a read-only second level cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, spring-webflow

I'm trying to improve the performance of a Java 7,Spring 3.1,Webflow 3.1,Hibernate 3.6 application. The main issue is for each user there Web-flow persistance-context is very large and the application runs out of RAM quickly. Most of the data in the context is read only entity data, static data like labels, lists etc ... that can be shared across these Web-flow persistance-contexts.

After reading a number of posts on caching and performance I believe the best approach is to use a second level cache and mark these objects as read only. This will share these objects across each persistance-context.

However my question is when these objects are loaded from the shared cache does the Web-flow persistance-context share a reference to a global ready-only entity or will there be a copy of this read-only entity in each Web-flow persistance-context i.e the look up will be faster but the size of the contexts will stay the same?

Thanks